# How to Sort Table header/row data in asp.net

Tags: .net, sql-server

I want to Show Result Year Wise. Data is coming from databse. I am using Table Control of .NET to Display data. I am not able to adjust Data with Year...

I want display data as below link

[image]

Please help, Tell me how to Display Year on Top of the cells and dipslay other data below year.

Comment: data where year = "input year"

Comment: What you have tried so far

Comment: I have edited Question. Please check. I am using Table Control. I am able to Fetch all the data. But Not able to Set Desired Look while data is fatching from database

Answer (score 0):

Use `ORDER BY YEAR` in your query...